# LDAC/APTX support on Linux?

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, audio-player

I just discovered that "pulseaudio-module-bt" will not be supported anymore and will be deprecated.
[https://github.com/EHfive/pulseaudio-modules-bt/issues/154]

Are there any stable software solutions I can use to play LDAC/APTX as of now and in the close future (for 20.04~21.04)?

Comment: Yes, the pulse-based solution (that's not in Ubuntu) is going away in favor of a pipewire-based solution. It's up to the community to test the new solution (the `pipewire` package) and to file bugs. Try pipewire in the pre-release 21.04, and file a bug report if it fails. That's how software becomes stable.